# react state changing state to make code from visible to hidden

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use a button to change the display to bring up new code using state. right now the button isn't switching from .hidden to .show. I want to click the button and have .binocularView, .binocularText, and resumeDownload come up.

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

class test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showHideView: "hidden"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="firstPage">
          <h1> Looking for a Project Manager? </h1>
          <h2> Take a peek inside </h2>
          <div className="buttonContainer">
            <button
              onClick={this.toggleView.bind(this)}
              className="binocularButton"
            >
              <div className={this.state.showHideView}>
                <div className="binocularView">
                  <h6 className="binocluarText">I am looking for you too</h6>
                  <a
                    className="resume-download"
                    href="/static/ScottFosterResume.pdf"
                    download="Scott-Foster-Resume"
                  >
                    Download PDF Resume
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <style jsx>{`
          @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond|Quicksand");
          @font-face {
            font-family: "EB Garamond", serif;
            src: url("../static/fonts/ebgaramond/EBGaramond-Regular.ttf")
              format("truetype");
          }
          h1 {
            text-align: center;
            justify-self: center;
            font-family: "EB Garamond", serif;
          }
          h2 {
            text-align: center;
            justify-self: center;
            font-family: "EB Garamond", serif;
          }
          .firstPage {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            background-image: url("/static/img/binoculars-fog-foggy-1136815.jpg");
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
          }
          .buttonContainer {
            position: fixed;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
          }
          .binocularButton {
            height: 9%;
            width: 9%;
            position: relative;
            color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
            justify-content: center;
            margin-top: 12%;
            margin-left: 40%;
            padding: 10%;
            border-radius: 50%;
            opacity: 0;
            z-index: 1;
          }
          .show {
            visibility: visable;
          }
          .hidden {
            visibility: hidden;
            display: none;
          }
          .binocularView {
            transform: scale(5);
            transform: 100s ease-in-out;
            opacity: 1;
            background-attachment: inherit;
            background-image: url("/static/img/DSCF6548.jpg");
            background-size: cover;
            position: fixed;
            top: 20%;
            left: 5%;
            width: 35%;
            display: block;
            align-items: top;
          }
          .binocluarText {
            color: black;
            width: ;
          }
          .resume-download {
            text-decoration: none;
            background: #054a25;
            color: white;
            padding: 5px;
            justify-content: flex-start;
          }
        `}</style>
      </div>
    );
  }

  toggleView() {
    var css = this.state.showHideView === "hidden" ? "hidden" : "show";
    this.setState({ showHideView: css });
  }
}

export default test;
```

Comment: Off topic: It's good practice to start component names with an uppercase letter, i.e. `Test` instead of `test`.

Comment: Thank I should get in better practice of that.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
var css = (this.state.showHideView === "hidden") ? "hidden" : "show";
```

to

```
var css = (this.state.showHideView === "hidden") ? "show" : "hidden";
```

Comment: Awesome that fixed the change from hidden to show but the children are not showing up.

Comment: then you need to fix your HTML/CSS